# How to create a cascading Dropdown List of 2?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't know what else to do. I want to Create a set of cascading select lists, where the selection of an item from the first list determines which list to display in the second list.I would like to know how to do it if someone could give me a clearer explanation please

```js
let data = [
    { item: 'Fruits', subitems: ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'watermelon'] },
    { item: 'Meals', subitems: ['chicken', 'bacon', 'pork', 'beef'] },
    { item: 'Animals', subitems: ['cat', 'rabbit', 'mouse', 'lion'] },
    {
      item: 'Brands Laptops',
      subitems: ['Dell', 'HP', 'Apple', 'Sony'],
    },
  ];


  window.onload = function() {
  var itemSel = document.getElementById("item");
  var subitemSel = document.getElementById("subitems");

  for (var x in data) {
    itemSel.options[itemSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  itemSel.onchange = function() {
  //empty 
  subitemSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in itemObject[this.value]) {
      subitemSel.options[subitemSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>

    <script defer type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <h1>Moshe Brito</h1>
      <h2>41088278</h2>
    </header>
    <main>
      <!-- content will be built here by javascript -->
      <div>
        <label for="first">First List</label>
        <select id="first" name="first">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please select first</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="second">Second List</label>
        <select id="second" name="second">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please select second</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use invalid value for `getElementById()`.
Those must refer to real HTML `id` attribute but you refer **all** of them to not exists.
The result in console showing error *TypeError: itemSel is null*.

The select text in `Option()` is in first argument. See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option).
If you use just `x in data` then `x` will be index number. It is okay to use it in `value` attribute but select text should be readable. So, it should be `data[x].item` in the first `Option()` argument.

Now go to inside the `onchange` event. You use undeclared `itemObject` variable and when first select box has been changed, it will be error here.
This variable must be replace with `data[this.value].subitems` if you want to list sub items property.

##### Full code.

```js
let data = [{
    item: 'Fruits',
    subitems: ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'watermelon']
  },
  {
    item: 'Meals',
    subitems: ['chicken', 'bacon', 'pork', 'beef']
  },
  {
    item: 'Animals',
    subitems: ['cat', 'rabbit', 'mouse', 'lion']
  },
  {
    item: 'Brands Laptops',
    subitems: ['Dell', 'HP', 'Apple', 'Sony'],
  },
];


window.onload = function() {
  var itemSel = document.getElementById("first");
  var subitemSel = document.getElementById("second");

  for (var x in data) {
    itemSel.options[itemSel.options.length] = new Option(data[x].item, x);
  }
  itemSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty 
    subitemSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y of data[this.value].subitems) {
      subitemSel.options[subitemSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Moshe Brito</h1>
  <h2>41088278</h2>
</header>
<main>
  <!-- content will be built here by javascript -->
  <div>
    <label for="first">First List</label>
    <select id="first" name="first">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select first</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="second">Second List</label>
    <select id="second" name="second">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select second</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</main>
```